# What database to use for temporary data storage?

Tags: node.js, heroku, sqlite

Creating a Node.js server, on Heroku. 
I only need to store data for around 30min-1 hr at a time, then, I can release the data.

Heroku recommends not using SQLite because it is an on memory database, and will get reset every time the server goes to sleep.

Since I don't need the data for very long, is it okay if I go through with this?

If you're curious, the project is to track timestamps of summoner spells that occur in a game of League of Legends. Since League of Legends games only last around 30min-1hr, I don't need the hold data for very long.

Comment: Please refer to Stack Overflow's Help section page on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is not an in-memory database. It stores the tables in a database file. In-memory tables are just an optional feature. The advantage of SQLite is that no setup or administration is needed, since it is embedded in your application. It has a small footprint, is very well tested and is actively developed. SQLite is the right choice.

Maybe the confusion comes from misunderstanding "embedded in your application". It is *the database engine's code* that is embedded, not the database and its tables.